# Want to show deleted items in Bin - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-apk

I want to add deleted items in **Bin** where I can restore or delete permanently. I used things which is listed below. However, I want to add deleted data in **deletedList**. So, How Can I? So, please help me.

```
List deletedList = [];
void delete() {
    allCategory.removeWhere((element) => element.isSelected == true);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
deletedItemList = (allCategory.where((element) => element.isSelected == true)).toList();
allCategory.removeWhere((element) => element.isSelected == true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through allCategory list, check if isSelected==true, then first add to deletedList then remove from allCategory list.

```
  for(int i=0; i<allCategory.length; i++){
    if(allCategory[i].isSelected==true) {
        deletedList.add(allCategory[i]);
        allCategory.removeAt(i);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `removeAt` itself returns the deleted item. So a simple one liner could be `deletedList.add(allCategory.removeAt(i))`